# SQL database calculation for null variable using other components

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image]

I'm looking to calculate the null variable by using predifined weights on a healthcare calculator and I want the output to be a sum of the variables weights over the total available weights. As you can see below this would hopefully be "sum/8".

```
CREATE TABLE `trial`.`trial` ( `Name` TEXT NULL , `Age` INT NULL , `BP systolic` INT NULL , `BP diastolic` INT NULL ,`Clinical features of the TIA` TEXT NULL , `Duration of symptoms` INT NULL , `History of diabetes` TEXT NULL , `ABCD² Score for TIA` FLOAT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `trial` (`Name`, `Age`, `BP systolic`, `BP diastolic`, `Clinical features of the TIA`, `Duration of symptoms`, `History of diabetes`, `ABCD² Score for TIA`) VALUES ('Person A', '71', '137', '85', 'Speech disturbance without weakness', '17', 'Yes', NULL);

INSERT INTO `trial` (`Name`, `Age`, `BP systolic`, `BP diastolic`, `Clinical features of the TIA`, `Duration of symptoms`, `History of diabetes`, `ABCD² Score for TIA`) VALUES ('Person B', '92', '125', '78', 'Other symptoms', '43', 'Yes', NULL);
INSERT INTO `trial` (`Name`, `Age`, `BP systolic`, `BP diastolic`, `Clinical features of the TIA`, `Duration of symptoms`, `History of diabetes`, `ABCD² Score for TIA`) VALUES ('Person C', '27', '130', '90', 'Other symptoms', '34', 'No', NULL);

update trial 
set ABCD² Score for TIA = case when ( 
case when Age = >=60 then 1 else 0 end 
+ case when BP systolic = >= 140 then 1 else 0 end 
+ case when BP diastolic = >=90 then 1 else 0 end 
+ case when Clinical features of the TIA = 'Unilateral weakness' then 2 end 
+ case when Clinical features of the TIA = 'Speech disturbance without weakness' then 1 end
+ case when Clinical features of the TIA = 'Other symptoms' then 0 end 
+ case when Duration of symptoms = <10   then 0 end 
+ case when Duration of symptoms = 10-59 then 1 end 
+ case when Duration of symptoms = >= 60 then 2 end
+ case when History of diabetes = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end
) sum/8 
where ABCD² Score for TIA is null
```

Comment: You can't write `= >=60`. It should just be `>= 60`.

Comment: Why do you have nested case expressions?

Comment: Having spaces in column names make things more complicated that they need to be. Here, you need to quote all these identifiers in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fix your CASE expressions and use MySql's feature to evaluate boolean expressions as 1 or 0:

```
update trial 
set `ABCD² Score for TIA` = ( 
  (Age >= 60) + (`BP systolic` >= 140) + (`BP diastolic` >= 90) +
  case `Clinical features of the TIA`
    when 'Unilateral weakness' then 2 
    when 'Speech disturbance without weakness' then 1 
    when 'Other symptoms' then 0 
  end +  
  case
    when `Duration of symptoms` >= 60 then 2
    when `Duration of symptoms` >= 10 then 1
    when `Duration of symptoms` < 10 then 0
  end + 
  (`History of diabetes` = 'Yes')
) / 8 
where `ABCD² Score for TIA` is null
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d43ad650cbbfdfa899ca03e2bb38d5d3).
Results:

```
> Name     | Age | BP systolic | BP diastolic | Clinical features of the TIA        | Duration of symptoms | History of diabetes | ABCD² Score for TIA
> :------- | --: | ----------: | -----------: | :---------------------------------- | -------------------: | :------------------ | -------------------:
> Person A |  71 |         137 |           85 | Speech disturbance without weakness |                   17 | Yes                 |                  0.5
> Person B |  92 |         125 |           78 | Other symptoms                      |                   43 | Yes                 |                0.375
> Person C |  27 |         130 |           90 | Other symptoms                      |                   34 | No                  |                 0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

Yuo don't need `CASE` expressions when the values are either 1 or 0. The value of a condition is `1` when it's true, `0` otherwise. So just use the condition directly.

And you don't need the cases to be nested inside another case.

You need backticks around all the column names that contain spaces.

```
UPDATE trial
SET `ABCD² Score for TIA` = (
    Age >= 60
    + `BP systolic` >= 140
    + `BP diastolic >= 90`
    + (case `Clinical features of the TIA`
            WHEN 'Unilateral weakness' then 2
            WHEN 'Speech disturbance without weakness' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END)
    + (case when `Duration of symptoms` BETWEEN 10 AND 59 THEN 1
            when `Duration of symptoms` >= 60 then 2
            ELSE 0 
       END)
    + `History of diabetes` = 'Yes')
WHERE `ABCD² Score for TIA` IS NULL
```